# How to print up to 40 rows in DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to get data from csv and output it to the console (ie, command line).
I have 30 columns, but I can only output 5 to 6 columns.

`df = pd.read_csv(csv_raw)`

`print(df.head())`

```
         date        level   mark       source  
0  2022-01-01     A        1         facebook
1  2022-01-01     B        2         facebook
2  2022-01-01     C        12       facebook
3  2022-01-01     D        53       facebook
4  2022-01-01     T        22       facebook
```

If I display all 30 columns it turns out like this:

`print(df.head(30))`

```
          date       ...    source
0   2022-01-01  ...  facebook
1   2022-01-01  ...  facebook
2   2022-01-01  ...  facebook
3   2022-01-01  ...  facebook
4   2022-01-01  ...  facebook
5   2022-01-01  ...  facebook
```

when i try `pd.options.display.max_columns = 50`
it returns me  like that:

```
         date                               level  clicks  \
0  2022-01-01                                 A       1   
1  2022-01-01                                 B       2   
2  2022-01-01                                 C       12   
3  2022-01-01                                 D       53   
4  2022-01-01                                 T       22   
5  2022-01-01  Free trial, upgrade to basic at https://www.wi...       1   

     source  
0   facebook  
1   facebook  
2   facebook  
3   facebook  
4   facebook  
5   facebook
```

Is it possible somehow to display more than 5 columns as in the first case?

Comment: the output is from jupyter or cmd?

Comment: @perpetualstudent cmd

Comment: can you try this? `pd.options.display.max_columns = 50`

Comment: @perpetualstudent i have tried you answer and edit my question, but it doesn't work because columns moved to another place, some kind of incorrect formatting

Comment: try these 3 lines: `pd.options.display.width = None` and `pd.options.display.max_columns = None` and this `pd.options.display.max_colwidth = None`

Comment: @perpetualstudent tanks it helped. but do you have any idea how to delete this line `Free trial, upgrade to basic at https://www.windsor.ai/pricing/`?

Comment: to delete row index 5 in df, use `df.drop(5, inplace=True)`

Comment: Nice, that's great! Happy coding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 dataframe settings to be set to display the desired output

(1) Set the overall width (number of characters)
`pd.options.display.width = 500`
`pd.options.display.width = None    #for unlimited`

(2) Set the maximum columns count (number of columns)
`pd.options.display.max_columns = 50`
`pd.options.display.max_columns = None    #for unlimited`

(3) Set the maximum width of each column (number of characters)
`pd.options.display.max_colwidth = 30`
`pd.options.display.max_colwidth = None    #for unlimited`

There is a row (index 5) having the value `Free trial, upgrade to basic at https://www.wi...`  which is making a mess of the columns. To delete this row, use:
`df.drop(5, inplace=True)`